# How to inject Javascript to GeckoView on Android

Tags: android, firefox, mozilla, gecko, geckoview

I want to use `GeckoView` in my project. But I need to run some Javascript code in this project. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "inject javascript"? Can you provide an example of your use-case?

Comment: Something like this : https://medium.com/appunite-edu-collection/webview-with-injected-js-script-13eb1e0257c9

Answer (score 3):

One possible way could be to use the [`GeckoSession.loadUri` API](https://mozilla.github.io/geckoview/javadoc/mozilla-central/org/mozilla/geckoview/GeckoSession.html#loadUri-java.lang.String-) to inject the JavaScript code

```
loadUri("javascript:{js_code}")
```

This used to work, I'm not sure it works any longer :)

**Edit** - another option would be to create a WebExtension to interact with content. GeckoView has  [some documentation here](https://mozilla.github.io/geckoview/consumer/docs/web-extensions). You should be able to declare a content script file name in the extension's manifest and bundle the content script with your extension.

Comment: nope, it's not working for us. I'm still searching.

Comment: I've slightly tweaked my answer to provide a second option, let me know if that works.

Comment: Really thanks for your effort, I appreciate that.
I've searched WebExtensions too. I think WebExtensions are used to run .js files from resource but I want to work with javascript in the loaded page. So WebExtension won't work for my case, was it?